# Parsing JSON and put it in HashMap

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap, baseadapter

I have a json pattern like this

```
objects: [
    -{
        category: {
            id: 4,
            image: "category image url",
            title: "LIGHT"
        },
        create_time: "2014-03-20T17:57:23",
        file_url: "file url",
        id: 26,
        title: "Note",
        user: {
            avatar: "thumb url",
            id: 12,
            name: "user name"
        }
    }
    -{
        category: {
            id: 1,
            image: "category image url",
            title: "HEAVY"
        },
        create_time: "2014-03-20T17:57:23",
        file_url: "file url",
        id: 25,
        title: "Photo",
        user: {
            avatar: "thumb url",
            id: 2,
            name: "user name"
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
]
```

When i parsed this block everything is okay until when i want to put parsed nodes to Hashmap.
for parsing i defin nodes and object as TAG like

```
public static final String TAG_CAT_ID           = "id";
public static final String TAG_TONE_ID          = "id";
public static final String TAG_USER_ID          = "id";
public static final String TAG_CAT_TITLE        = "title";
public static final String TAG_TITLE            = "title";
```

then i parsed them in For loop and save results as String like this:

```
String cat_id                   = category.getString(TAG_CAT_ID);
String cat_title                = category.getString(TAG_CAT_TITLE);
String file_id                  = file.getString(TAG_TONE_ID);
String file_title               = file.getString(TAG_TITLE);
String user_id                  = user.getString(TAG_USER_ID);
```

As i should say....category, file and user defined as JSON Object.
till now everythin is okay and i can get result as i want:

```
cat_id     -> 4
cat_title  -> LIGHT
file_id    -> 26
file_title -> Note
user_id    -> 12
----------------------
cat_id     -> 1
cat_title  -> HEAVY
file_id    -> 25
file_title -> Photo
user_id    -> 2
```

after this section i put this result in HashMap like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TAG_CAT_ID, cat_id);
map.put(TAG_TONE_ID, tone_id);
map.put(TAG_USER_ID, user_id);
```

disaster happened!! for each object...hash map returns only one id!!!!!
same id for cat_id, file_id, user_id.......and one title for cat_title and file_title!!!

where is my wrong?!

Comment: if you put value with existing key to `HashMap`, the previous value at this key will be over-written. Does it make sense?

Comment: Disaster happens because you are putting TAG_CAT_ID, TAG_TONE_ID, TAG_USER_ID which all have the same string value. Hashmap can only have unique keys. Duplicates will get overwritten.

Comment: Well....what i should do?! i cant change api :(

Comment: You can always use MultiMap. http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html In this case you will have three keys with the the same name - "id". Not sure how you will be able to differentiate them. Maybe MultiMap keeps the order; I have never used it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final String TAG_CAT_ID           = "id";
public static final String TAG_TONE_ID          = "id";
public static final String TAG_USER_ID          = "id";
```

These ID-s are same, so when you put the values, you use the same key. This way you overwrite the "id" key's value 3 times.

Your code equivalent to this:

```
map.put("id", cat_id);
map.put("id", tone_id);
map.put("id", user_id);
```

You should define your ID-s unique.

Comment: Look at the javadoc of the Hashmap.put() method.

Comment: Why should I look on that?

Comment: just like Julien has written - read the javadoc. Everytime you assign value to the key, old value (if exists) is being overwritten.

Comment: Ohh, I thougt you ask me to read the JavaDoc:) Somewhy MAY3AM's comment did not show.

Comment: Thanks Guys.....i define final string tags and solved this issue by assigning cat_id, file_id and user_id instead of id, id and id :D